# Update label in a Tray

Tags: java, awt

Having a class Tray for a java desktop application, I have to update the value of the disk quota used when the popup is opened

1) Tray class

```
    public class Tray implements Observer {

        static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Tray.class);
        static WDServer wds;
        static StatusWindow sw;
        boolean connected;
        TrayIcon trayIcon;
        String volSize = "";

        public Tray() {

            log.info("installing system tray menu");

            if (SystemTray.isSupported()) {

                TrayUtils tu = new TrayUtils(1000);

                final SystemTray sysTray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
                final PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu();

                MenuItem quotaDisk = new MenuItem(tu.getLabelDisk());
                popup.add(quotaDisk);
                popup.addSeparator();
...
```

2) Nested TrayUtils class with runnable interface

```
public class TrayUtils extends Thread implements Runnable {

        long delay;
        long bytes;
        String labelDisk = "";

        public TrayUtils(long delay) {
            this.delay = delay;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    setBytes(FileUtils.sizeOfDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/.ubi/data")));
                    Thread.sleep(this.delay);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    log.error("error checking disk space used");
                }

                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        setLabelDisk("Storage Used: " + FileUtils.byteCountToDisplaySize(getBytes()));
                    }
                });
            }

        }

<getters & setters here>
    }
```

Why can't I have the storage status in the popup ? What would be the right design to implement these feature ?

I have to use `awt`, so `JLabel` here is not welcome.

Comment: What's in `setLabelDisk`?

Comment: Derived from apache.common.io: the method to convert bytes in a human readable value; the setter  public void setLabelDisk(String labelDisk) {
            this.labelDisk = labelDisk;
        }

Comment: Then where's the rest of your GUI? Where do you create your [`Label`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Label.html) or whatever `awt` component you use??

Comment: The label is created with the instance of java.awt.MenuItem : MenuItem quotaDisk = new MenuItem("label");

Comment: Please restate your question. What is exactly "*storage status in the popup*"? What stops you from showing it? I suggest you edit your question providing more details of the problem at hand and your particular problems.

Comment: Well, i believe the essential part has been described in the code: that is to say the Tray Constructor calls the TrayUtils.getLabelDisk() method to build the quota disk label, but it's not refreshing the string value... The rest of the gui works well and i think there's no need to attach an actionListener to quotaDisk here, but i can be wrong..

Comment: Which `string value`? Where is the code that is supposed to do such refresh?

Comment: The code supposed to refresh is in TrayUtils (method run()) and the String to update is labelDisk in TrayUtils, which i get from Tray() constructor

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41057/discussion-between-pm-77-1-and-ludo-rj)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to PM, the javax.swing.Timer did the job:

```
// Update space used every 1s
            ActionListener taskQuota = new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    quotaDisk.setLabel("Storage used: " + checkVolSize());
                }
            };
            new Timer(1000, taskQuota).start();
```